# How to get all elements after selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I include the last element aswell?

```js
$('div.current').nextUntil("div:last").css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div class="current">Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>
<div>Sixth</div>
<div>Seventh</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `nextAll()` instead:

```js
$('div.current').nextAll().addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #00F; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div class="current">Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>
<div>Sixth</div>
<div>Seventh</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot that there was a nextAll button.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `andSelf` method in combination with `next()` method.

> `andSelf` method adds the previous set of elements on the stack to the
>   current set.

```js
$('div.current').nextUntil("div:last").andSelf().next().css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div class="current">Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>
<div>Sixth</div>
<div>Seventh</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [general sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) `~` in your selector

```js
$('div.current ~ div').css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div class="current">Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>
<div>Sixth</div>
<div>Seventh</div>
```

Comment: I never knew about this functionality. I will sure use this more often now :) Thanks for informing me about this.

Comment: np. I added a link to the spec so that you can read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass no parameter inside `nextUntil()` and it will select all the next following elements.

Or maybe use `nextAll()`.

```js
$('div.current').nextUntil().css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div class="current">Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>
<div>Sixth</div>
<div>Seventh</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nextAll method of jquery instead of nextUntil.

```js
$('div.current').nextAll().css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div class="current">Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>
<div>Sixth</div>
<div>Seventh</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you wanted to do with your code ^^

```js
$('div.current').nextUntil("html").css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div class="current">Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>
<div>Sixth</div>
<div>Seventh</div>
```